# How can I get the standard error of an AUC in ROCR?

Tags: r, roc

I'm using ROCR to obtain the AUC indices. I want to have also the standard errors of the AUC but in the default outputs they are not shown. Is there any way of obtaining them?

Example:

```
library(ROCR)
a<-rnorm(100,1)
b<-sample(0:1,100,TRUE)
pred<-prediction(a,b)
auc<-performance(pred,"auc")
auc@y.values
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you keen on ROCR or did you mean "in R"? Because I don't think you can do that with ROCR, at least not directly.

Comment: I would rather prefer to do it within ROCR, but if it can be done easily in another way I would be happy to hear about it. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, ROCR doesn't calculate standard errors, which is why the aren't shown.

You can obtain them with the `pROC` package (disclaimer: I am its author).

```
myROC <- roc(b, a) 
var(myROC)
```

Take the square root to obtain the standard deviation, which in this case is the standard error (because the AUC is a sample-mean).